# is it possible to have a attribute.setter method in a python class attribute without @property

Tags: python, class, object

```
class yes:
    def __init__(self):
       self.some_attribute = "123";

    @some_attribute.setter
    def some_attribute_setter(self, value):
       #whatever code goes here
```

in the above code I'd like to be able to do **some_attribute.setter** without having to set a `@property` for **some_attribute** is that possible? (if so, how?)

Comment: No, that doesn't make any sense. `property` is a *type of object*, a descriptor.  `some_attribute` *isn't even in scope* when you try to do `@some_attribute.setter`. It is important to understand, `@some_decorator`  above `def some_func` syntax is just sugar for `def some_func` then `some_func = decorator(some_func)`

Comment: If you really want a deep dive on this, read about what the decorator syntax actually means, then read this: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html

Comment: why not want the getter with @property ?